# Need help adjusting PHP code, need commas after all terms except the last

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't understand PHP very well but I'm trying to adjust this code below. I want the terms to all have a comma after them except for the last one. Right now the output looks like this:

***Audience:*** Pre-School, High School, Adult,

However I need it to look like this:

***Audience:*** Pre-School, High School, Adult

I realize there are similar questions out there that already answer this question, but since I am clueless when it comes to PHP I don't know how to incorporate those solutions with this code I already have. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php 
$terms = get_terms( 'Audience' );
 if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     echo '<p><strong>Audience:</strong> ';
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo '' . $term->name . ', ';

     }
     echo '</p>';
 }
?>
```

Comment: `echo implode(',', array_map(function($value) { return $value->name; }, $terms));` instead of your `foreach` loop

Comment: Thank you Mark this worked! This only issue is now my output looks like this, with the Audience heading at the end:

Adults, Children & Families, Elementary School, High School, Middle School, Preschool **Audience:**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either count during the foreach loop;

```
$i = 1;
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '' . $term->name;
    if ($i < count($terms)) {
        echo ', ';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Or you can simply load it all into a variable and then crop the last comma and space off.

```
$output = '';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $output .= $term->name . ', ';
}
echo substr($output,0,-2);
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! I used the counting during the foreach loop; code. Just had a slight syntax error, '($i < count(terms))' but once fixed it worked.

Comment: I've adjusted my answer to fix that missing closing bracket.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the amazingly convenient function [`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

```
echo implode(", ", $terms);
```

Comment: thanks! so would i just add it to the end like this? 


<?php 
$terms = get_terms( 'Audience' );
 if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     echo '<p><strong>Audience:</strong> ';
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo '' . $term->name . ', ';

     }
     echo '</p>';
     echo implode(", ", $terms);
 }
?>

Comment: Put it in place of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: p.s. sorry i posted that a million times, trying to figure out how to use this site ;)

Comment: Actually yeah, @Halcyon has come up with a far simpler way than my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Save the line to a variable during the loop and then remove the last character before printing it. Not the most elegant solution but it works

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$terms = get_terms( 'Audience' );
 if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     echo '<p><strong>Audience:</strong> ';
     $len = count($terms);
     $i = 0;
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       i++;
       echo '' . $term->name . ($i < $len  ? ', ' : '');

     }
     echo '</p>';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use trim() https://www.php.net/trim

```
$string = '';
$terms = get_terms( 'Audience' );
 if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     $string .= '<p><strong>Audience:</strong> ';
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       $string .= '' . $term->name . ', ';

     }
     $string .= "</p>";
     echo trim($string, ',');
 }
?>
```

You can use it to remove strings from the start and end of your whole string.